# Configure rTorrent to stop downloading after a certain file size

Tags: linux, debian, script, bittorrent, rtorrent

I am looking for a way to configure rTorrent to stop downloading all torrents after they have downloaded x amount. For example, specify 15mb and as soon as the torrent reaches that size have it finish downloading the pieces it has requested and then start seeding partially completed. If you can even point me in the right direction script wise, shell or python and how to interact with tTorrent like this I would consider it answered, thanks.

Clarification:

The reason for this is I'm trying to come up with a way to build ratio on a site where torrents are added very fast and at a very high frequency. I download and add the torrents to rTorrent automatically via RSS, but I only want to download a small amount and seed that small piece while there are still a lot of people in the swarm (swarm drops off very quickly) and come out with a positive ratio from that small piece, beating the ratio clock so to speak. I thought it would be an interesting all be it somewhat impractical exercise in shell scripting, if rTorrent can be hooked into like that, documentation is sparse in some areas.

Comment: It seems like a weird goal... Can you talk more about why you want to do this? What are you trying to accomplish? Maybe we could help solve your issue in a better way.  If your client can't normally do this, you may have to switch to a different client, but I've never heard of this feature.

Comment: Edited first post to try and clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the current stable version of rTorrent (0.8.6), there are very few "triggering" options. Where previously (0.7 and below, if memory serves) there was a "schedule" command you can drop in your rtorrent rc, now there is only the ratio.* grouping.

That means that we've gone from this in previous versions:

```
# example: stop at ratio 2.0 with at least 200 MB uploaded, or else ratio 20.0  
schedule = ratio,60,60,"stop_on_ratio=200,200M,2000"
```

To this is 0.8:

```
ratio.enable=

ratio.min.set=100  
ratio.max.set=300  
ratio.upload.set=200M

system.method.set = group.seeding.ratio.command, d.close=, d.erase=
```

You would imagine you could set `ratio.min` to 0, and `ratio.upload` to 15M, unfortunately I came across a relevant [ticket on libtorrent's TRAC](http://libtorrent.rakshasa.no/ticket/2218).

Per the comment on that ticket, the ratio settings will only fire upon completion, and continue to be evaluated after the fact.

I don't believe rTorrent/libTorrent offers what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you for a very through answer, off to look for other solution.